# Boolean won't carry over to next line?

Tags: java

I was just about to finish up a program I made but I came across one problem. I have the boolean called 'mayWater' but it won't carry over to my next part of the program which is the 'pulic void result' line. Here it is.

```
private boolean mayWater(String userMonth, String userDay, String userGroup) {

    boolean outcome = false;
    switch (userMonth)

    {
    //True statements go here

    default:
        outcome = false;
        break;

    }
    return outcome;
}


public void result(String userGroup, String userMonth, String userDay) {

    System.out.println("The group you mentioned earlier was Group : "
            + userGroup + ".");
    System.out.println("You wished to water on a " + userDay
            + " in the month of " + userMonth + ".");
//This below line was my problem    
if (mayWater()) 

It was then changed to the following:

    if (mayWater(String userGroup, String userMonth, String userDay))
```

Comment: `canWater` takes 3 `String` arguments

Answer (score 1):

`canWater` is a method with 3 arguments - `canWater(String userMonth, String userDay, String userGroup)`.

You can't call it with no arguments.

Call it like this :

```
if (canWater(userMonth, userDay, userGroup)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! but now my problem is my "System.out.println" lines dont work. It only asks the questions and for my input and stops there. It looks like this :

Comment: Please enter your group letters [A through F] :(ex. B)
A
Please enter the month you wish to water on[January through December]:(ex. February)
FEBRUARY
Lastly, enter the day you wish to water on[Monday through Saturday]:(ex. Monday)
MONDAY

Comment: @Xirol Perhaps you want to call your `result` method from your `main` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your `canWater` method expects three parameters and you are not passing those three parameters.

You need to pass three parameters to `canWater` method like:

```
if (canWater(userMonth, userDay, userGroup)) {
```